# I have a domain name and an installed Certificate, that I want to assign to a running localhost application

Tags: windows, ssl, localhost, appdomain

I have :

1. A running application on localhost:8080
2. A domain name "www.domain.com"
3. An installed SSL Certificate

Now my first Issue is that, I want to access my application from url: http://www.domain.com

and second part is to assign the certificate, making the url:
https://www.domain.com

How can i do that in Windows? Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I used Ngnix for windows, and it worked for me.